# php mysql select having my row's data

Tags: php, mysql

my table structure is:

```
id    userid  collegeid startyr   endyr

1       1       5        1995     1998

2       1       6        1999     2001

3       3       6        1999     2001

4       4       6        2000     2003

5       5       5        1995     1998

6       5       6        2005     2008

7       7       10       1999     2001
```

i.e If my user id is 1. I am studing in college 5,6 in the year of 1995 to 1998 and 1999 to 2001

I want get the users (other than my id)
in the order of

1. In my college in my batch college 5 and 6 in the start year of 1995 and 1999
2. in my college in various batches

So the out put will be in the order of

```
id    userid  collegeid startyr   endyr
5       5       5        1995     1998 (My college my batch
3       3       6        1999     2001 (My college my batch
4       4       6        2000     2003 (My college another batch)
6       5       6        2005     2008 (My college another batch)
7       7       10       1999     2001
```

How to write the select query to get these dependency order.

Comment: I don't understand where the batch is being defined here.  Please edit your question and make it easier to follow.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: (Start year is same . Thats why I mentioned as my batch mate.

Comment: OK...I think I understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try ordering using a three-tiered `CASE` expression.  Highest priority records are those where both the college and batch matches your own.  Next are those records with matching college, but a different batch.  Finally, all other records follow these first two cases.  There is also a second part to the `ORDER BY` clause to order within each group ascending by the year (which seems to be what you expect).

```
SELECT id, userid, collegeid, startyr, endyr
FROM yourTable
WHERE userid <> 1
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN collegeid IN (5, 6) AND (startyr, endyr) IN
        ((1995, 1998), (1999, 2001)) THEN 1
         WHEN collegeid IN (5, 6)    THEN 2
         ELSE 3 END,
    startyr;
```

[image]

### Demo